# Цикл в java с String переменными

Tags: java, строки

Есть окно для ввода данных (string). Нужно, чтобы окно появлялось до тех пор, пока не введут правильный ответ. Если бы это были числовые значения - было бы проще, но с переменными стринг не получается.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String name2;
    name2=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("SAY MY NAME!");

    String title="Window message";
    int type=JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE;
    int type2=JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE;

    if (name2==null) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "okay...",title,type2);}

    else if (name2.equals("Trevor")) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU RIGHT!",title,type);}
```

И вот дальше вроде как цикл должен быть

```
    else for ...
        {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "TRY AGAIN!...",title,type2); 
        name2=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("SAY MY NAME! SAY-MY-NAME!!!?");}

        if (name2.equals("Trevor")) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU RIGHT!",title,type);}

}
}
```

Если бы я мог хотя бы без цикла сделать что-то типа

```
     else if (name2 !=="Trevor") {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "TRY       AGAIN!...",title,type2); 
        name2=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("SAY MY NAME! SAY-MY-NAME!!!?");}

        if (name2.equals("Trevor")) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU RIGHT!",title,type);}
```

Но `.equals()`  и == со стрингами не работают.

Comment: А как именно equals() не работает?

Comment: .equals() именно сравнивает значения, а мне нужно чтобы было "НЕ равно" != вот такое вот значение.

Comment: if (!"a".equals("b")) - тоже не работает?

Comment: Ну и сама структура программы странная. Надо бесконечный цикл делать с запросом ввода и выходом только при правильном ответе.

Comment: что я и пытаюсь сделать, просто я ее уже 10 раз изувечил и сам потерялся

Comment: В общем, вопрос был не о циклах, а о сравнении строк в Java и логическом отрицании...

Comment: ну да, спасибо дальше я сам разберусь

Comment: Восклицательный знак делает унарное отрицание. Всегда можно делать `if( ! true/false)`

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй так сделать

```
if (!"Trevor".equals(name2))
```

Comment: или записать "Trevor" в переменную и

      if (!name.equals(name2))

Comment: 1 вариант сработал, но думаю 2 тоже сработает, спасибо!

Comment: @altermim, присоединяюсь к совету, чтобы использовать цикл while до тех пор, пока не будет введено правильное имя

Comment: "или записать "Trevor" в переменную и if (!name.equals(name2))" это не обязательно, пул string создается еще при компиляторе и выйдет по сути тоже самое.

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
      // Show input dialog
} while (!name2.equals("Trevor"));
```

Comment: Прикольно. И как же это будет работать? Окно создастся, создастся.. И программа такая "кря.". Это вам не паскаль, `until`...

Comment: Oй, простите, это же цикл с постусловием... :)